# Integrating one iOS project into another iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have one existing project. Now i have developed one project with some new feature. Need to integrate the existing project to this. When i run this project it shows this app functionalities. On that one button click to show the existing project home page and continue that existing project. I need to enter the existing project and use that functionalities and UI whatever and exit from that to continue the current project. Kindly give me solution. If you don't know requirement ping me i will explain with detail.

Comment: Make the framework of one project and add the framework into Master project

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly add the project folder of your project to your existing project and then once you are in your existing project on the click of your button you can do this,

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard stoaryboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
```

This will load the storyboard of your new project, if you have made the project using xib then you can load the xib as well

Then you can,

```
ViewController *firstController= [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstController"];
```

This will load the view controller of your new project, then you can do this to present this view controller,

```
[self.viewController presentViewController:firstController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will load your view controller now you can do what you want in your new project.

To comeback to your existing project you can set your new project delegate to be your old project and implement methods to comeback.

Hope this helps.

Comment: first project is a store app (menu, product list, cart,orders). Its has more viewcontrollers,images,third party integration and single storyboard. second project is banners ,offers, appointment,user login like functionality. Its also a more viewcontrollers, single storyboard. second project have store button to show first project viewcontrollers and also have option to exit to second project. How to integrate easily one project to another